# Converting from Non-basis coordinates to XYZ. Solving system of equations. Error volume

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, quadratic-forms

I have multiple points in 3D space. Each point has the distances to 3 points.
Those 3 points are:

- (50,0,0)
- (0,50,0)
- (0,0,50)

Lets call those distances $dx,dy,dz$
I want to find $x,y,z$ of those points, altough I'm sure there are restritions. The system of equations is:
$$ (x - 50)^2 + y^2 + z^2 = dx^2$$
$$x^2 + (y - 50)^2 + z^2 = dy^2$$
$$x^2 + y^2 + (z - 50)^2 = dz^2$$

I started resolving it, but it was becoming too much long. So I used mathematica, and got this solution:
$$root1 = -25000000 + 5000 dx^2 - dx^4 + 5000 dy^2 + 
          dx^2 dy^2 - dy^4 + 5000 dz^2 + dx^2 dz^2 + dy^2 dz^2 - 
          dz^4$$
There are two solutions, $(x1,y1,z1)$ and $(x2,y2,z2)$:

$$
x1 = \frac {1}{300} * \left(5000 - (2*dx*dx) + (dy*dy) + (dz*dz) - \sqrt{2} * \sqrt{root1} \right)
$$
$$
y1 = \frac {1}{300} * \left(5000 + (dx*dx) - (2*dy*dy) + (dz*dz) - \sqrt{2} * \sqrt{root1} \right)
$$
$$
z1 = \frac {1}{300} * \left(5000 + (dx*dx) + (dy*dy) - (2*dz*dz) - \sqrt{2} * \sqrt{root1} \right)
$$

$$
x2 = \frac {1}{300} * \left(5000 - (2*dx*dx) + (dy*dy) + (dz*dz) + \sqrt{2} * \sqrt{root1} \right)
$$
$$
y2 = \frac {1}{300} * \left(5000 + (dx*dx) - (2*dy*dy) + (dz*dz) + \sqrt{2} * \sqrt{root1} \right)
$$
$$
z2 = \frac {1}{300} * \left(5000 + (dx*dx) + (dy*dy) - (2*dz*dz) + \sqrt{2} * \sqrt{root1} \right)
$$

For some points both solution exist and are the same. But for others, root1 is negative, and therefore the solution doesn't exist. The problem is that those $dx,dy,dz$ infact exist, thats why I saved them, but I didnt save the exact values.
For example, to the point $(58, 73, 63)$ there is a solution, but for $(25, 44, 42)$ there is no solution. The real point that has a solution must be somewhere in a volume around that point.

My question is, how to find a close enough solution to an invalid point?

Comment: You formulate an optimisation problem (minimise the residues, for example minimize $\sum_{i=1}^3 (\|x-x_i\|_2 - d_i)^2$ Given $x_i \in\mathbb R^3$ and $d_i\in\mathbb R_+$ the distance of the unknown point to $x_i$.

Comment: thats interesting, good idea, I also found study material for those! thanks

Comment: Did this answer your question? If yes I can write the comment as an answer so you can mark the question as solved.

Comment: yes sure. I was just reading about known algorithms in wikipedia and google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you do is you formulate an optimisation problem with the objective function resembling the residue (the "deviation") from an ideal solution. The usual choice here is $\|x-x_i\|_2 \stackrel!= d_i$ wich leads to the objectives
$$(\|x-x_i\|_2 - d_i)^2$$
The square makes the function continuously differentiable (wich is nice) and the complete problem becomes
$$\min_{x\in\mathbb R^n} \sum_{i=1}^3 (\|x-x_i\|_2 - d_i)^2$$
Wich is clearly $\ge 0$ and $= 0$ iff $\|x-x_i\|_2 = d_i$ for all $i$, i.e. iff $x$ is a perfect solution. Solving this problem can be done using convex optimisation machinery.